# centering unicode text in button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, unicode

I have a button in which I am using bootstrap css, I have used unicode text for the button, and I want the unicode text to be font size at 30px and the button height to be 34px; but it seems like the text is not centering within the button.

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="height: 34px;"><span style="font-size:30px;">&#8649;</span></button>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: button height height: 34px; is compulsory ? if no then remove this from button

Comment: yes its is compulsory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achive this in 2 ways :

1. with line height
2. remove height

   **Update:** Update / Add this in your css file

   ```
   .btn{
       outline:none !important;
       }
   ```

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
     <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

   <style>
   .btn{
   outline:none !important;
   }
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>

   <div class="container">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="height: 34px; line-height: 16px; vertical-align:middle"><span style="font-size:30px;">&#8649;</span></button>  

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style=" line-height: 34px; vertical-align:middle"><span style="font-size:30px;">&#8649;</span></button>  
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: is `middle2` a valid `vertical-align` value

Comment: can you please tell me why the clicking effect is not getting much when i used bootstrap, In firefox I am getting some white dotted border line when clicked

Comment: what kind of clicking effect you mean? I hope both are looking same http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons

Comment: In firefox I am getting some white dotted border line when clicked for buttons